# Android Foreground service without notification - how to?

Tags: java, android

I have created foreground service for notifications in my application. It's working fine, the problem is to start the foreground service we need foreground notification which tell that your application is running
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmeSP.png). I don't want this notification. How I can remove that notification without killing the service.

This is how I'm starting the foreground service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    stopForeground(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
    Intent stopSelf = new Intent(this, Notification_Service.class);
    stopSelf.setAction("ACTION_STOP_SERVICE");
    PendingIntent pStopSelf = PendingIntent
            .getService(this, 0, stopSelf
                    , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Action action =
            new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                    0, "Close", pStopSelf
            ).build();
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("Ask Question")
            .setContentText("Ask Question is running")
            .addAction(action)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    startForeground(1, notification);
    notificationManager.cancel(1);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Session", MODE_PRIVATE);
    id = settings.getString("id", null);
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startMyOwnForeground();
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}

private void startMyOwnForeground() {
    Log.e("", "service running");
    get_notification();
}
```

**Retrofit call to get notification:**

```
  private void get_notification() {
        Call<ArrayList> call = apiInterface.getnotification(ApiClient.pin, id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList> call, Response<ArrayList> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i = i + 1) {
                        ArrayList<String> getdata = (ArrayList<String>) response.body().get(i);
                        String[] data = getdata.toArray(new String[0]);
                        if (data[5].equals("0")) {
                            switch (data[4]) {
                                case "comment":
                                    send_comment_notification(data[1], data[2], data[3], data[0]);
                                    break;
                                case "question":
                                    send_question_notification(data[3], data[0], data[1]);
                                    break;
                                case "answer":
                                    send_answer_notification(data[3], data[0], data[1]);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Good question following the question.

Comment: You cannot because that is the purpose of foreground service. It should be noticeable to user.

Comment: According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Types-of-services) every Foreground service must display a notification.

Comment: Then for notification which service I should use?

Comment: Except foreground all service got killed if the application is closed from task manager.

Comment: I'm getting the notification by retrofit request.

Comment: You should `FCM` for `notifications` which works based on `BroadcastReceiver`, it will take care of sending notifications to your app despite of App state.

Comment: Can you share an example code for this?

Comment: @rajan.kali can you explain with example?

Comment: @Xtenxionfacebook you can refer this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @rajan.kali For this we have to send notification manually from the firebase console right?

Comment: @rajan.kali I'm using retrofit to get notification. How I can send That Notification to Firebase console. I don't understand if application is killed how we can send notification to console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation of **Karsten Planz**

> You should either use the WorkManager API  to
> implement a background sync mechanism. Then you can use the
> NotificationBuilder to create a "local" notifiction.

Start the Task in your main activity by this:

```
  WorkRequest uploadWorkRequest =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
                        .build();
        WorkManager
                .getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                .enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

Now Create a class `NotificationWorker` and extends `Worker`. Place your `startMyOwnForeground` in **doWork** by returning  `Result.retry()`, this will make a recursive function.

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {

    Context  context;
  
    public NotificationWorker(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        startMyOwnForeground();
        return Result.retry();
    }
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {
        Log.e("", "service running");
        get_notification();
    }

    private void get_notification() {
        Call<ArrayList> call = apiInterface.getnotification(ApiClient.pin, id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList> call, Response<ArrayList> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i = i + 1) {
                        ArrayList<String> getdata = (ArrayList<String>) response.body().get(i);
                        String[] data = getdata.toArray(new String[0]);
                        if (data[5].equals("0")) {
                            switch (data[4]) {
                                case "comment":
                                    send_comment_notification(data[1], data[2], data[3], data[0]);
                                    break;
                                case "question":
                                    send_question_notification(data[3], data[0], data[1]);
                                    break;
                                case "answer":
                                    send_answer_notification(data[3], data[0], data[1]);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to show notifications using a "pull" approach instead of a "push" approach. For showing notifications which are triggered by some backend system you should normally use push notifications.

Only if you have no control over the backend system you could think about pulling regular updates from the server. But even then it probably would make sense to create your own backend (see also [BFF pattern](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/)) which pulls the updates and then sends push notifications to your app instead of each app pulling from the server.

As already suggested in the comments you should use FCM to push notifications from your server to your app. Check out the [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture?hl=en) for a good overview. The Android system and the Firebase SDK will do the heavy lifting for you and your app does not need to run in the background or foreground to receive notifications.

If you still want to pull in regular time intervals from a server, you should either use the [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) API or even use [sync adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters) to implement a background sync mechanism. Then you can use the [`NotificationBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) to create a "local" notifiction.

Comment: As, I have already overlooked FCM. let me check out the Work-Manager and Sync-Adapters.

Comment: Can you explain difference between pull and push?

Comment: I'm pulling data for notification then pushing the notification according to the data.

Comment: I don't want to change the structure for pulling the notification from retrofit.

Comment: Pull: App calls the Backend API e.g. every 5 minutes, then show a notification. Push: Backend calls FCM when there is a new notification and FCM triggers a notification on the device (via BroadcastReceiver). You should always prefer push in such a scenario as it is way more efficient.

Comment: How to change that approach to push?

Comment: Can you provide an example code for this?

Comment: You need to implement FCM on your server-side either using the Firebase SDK or the HTTP API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server?hl=en

Comment: Here are some examples on how to send messages to certain users/devices or to multiple devices: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=en

Comment: Your still missing the main point. He is getting the notification data from Retrofit API call. All the approaches looks great but still If the application is closed how he can get a API Call for notification. Is there Specific Class where he can place his API call then send messages by FCM?

Comment: @KarstenPlanz I think ahmad bajwa saying right.

Comment: @Xtenxionfacebook as I wrote when you want to pull the data from some API, you can use for example the WorkManager to schedule a background task. And to trigger a notification "locally" you don't need FCM then. You can just use the NotificationBuilder to trigger the notification: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification. I will update my answer with this information.

Comment: Ok I understand your point. If you provide code I will be very grateful to you. As it's new for me it will be hard  for me to implement it.